# Mule Flow design

Tags: esb, mule

In my application, a client sends a SOAP request through a JSP page to the Mule ESB and ESB routes it to a Weather Service. I want to send the response from the service to the client through ESB: how can I structure the flow to achieve this? Where will the response land in Mule ESB in first place?

```
<Flow>
Step1:inbound endpoint>
Step 2:<component>
Step 3:<outbound endpoint>
Step4:<component>
Step 5:<outbound endpoint>
<Flow>
```

Is this flow correct? Is this enough to pass the reponse to the client?

I have some questions on this:

1. From the outbound endpoint: can I send the response directly to the client without routing to the component?
2. Do I need to call the same component class again to pass the response?

Code snippets or samples regarding this will be a great help.

Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your endpoints are request-response, the message that will reach the end of your flow will be used as a response to the inbound endpoint.

In the response phase, Mule doesn't go through the flow elements it went through in the request phase. You could actually add components/transformers to execute only in the response phase by wrapping them in a <response> element.

So the answers are:

1. Yes.
2. No.

Comment: I have few more doubts to be clarified.                                                       1.If i can send the response from outbound directly means where can i do the SOAPtoPOJO transformation.Because service sends SOAP response but I want the reponse as a POJO object 
2.Please suggest me your idea on the flow structure formation.Is this ok?                                                          <Flow>
Step1:inbound endpoint>
Step 2:<component>
Step 3:<outbound endpoint>
<Flow>
4.Where the response will land in the Flow of ESB  from the Service.

Comment: CXF http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Consuming+Web+Services+with+CXF will do the SOAP to POJO conversion for you.

Comment: Can u give me idea where the response will land on ESB from services.Inbound or outbound?

Comment: probably you can take a look at transformers in mule.  http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE2USER/Using+Transformers

Answer (score 0):

For transforming the response u got from the service to whatever response as expected by the user. you should use outbound transformers to do so

probably you can take a look at transformers in mule.  http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE2USER/Using+Transformers

Comment: can u tell me where the response will land on Flow of ESB?

Comment: response wont land response will propagate back from the esb. responses can be customise in each and every point in the flow using our custom transformers.

Comment: transformers are nothing but for example say u r invoking a service from ur esb to external system the response from the external system will be customized or under go some process using transformers. It is more or less like interceptors in spring.

Comment: Adding to u inbound is any request from client to mule esb and outbound is mule esb system is requesting to external systems to get data. both the scenarios both request and response will be there.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Using+Perceptive+Flow+Design

https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Flows+and+Subflows
Mule applications are built around one or more flows. Typically, a Mule application begins processing a message it is received by an inbound endpoint in a flow. This flow can then either implement all processing stages, or route the message to other flows or subflows to perform specific tasks. Relative to the flow which triggered its execution, a flows and subflows can process messages either synchronously (see below, top) or asynchronously